# Solving a Compound Inequality Graph

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the solution set of $\{x\mid x < -5\}\cap\{x \mid x > 5\}$?

A. all numbers less than $-5$ and greater than $5$;

B. the numbers between $-5$ and $5$;

C. the empty set;

D. all real numbers.

Comment: What are your thoughts/what have you tried?

Comment: Translating (note the intersection): What numbers are both less than $-5$ *and* greater than $5$?

Comment: Seems like A and C are correct

Comment: @DavidMitra: all numbers less than $-5$ and greater than $5$ ;)

Comment: @user83116 : You really need to understand what "$\cap$" means to think about this.  A member of $A\cap B$ is a member of BOTH $A$ and $B$.  So ask yourself if there's some number that is a member of BOTH of these two sets.